# How to display data from Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data in a Map that needs to be displayed on the screen. How can I display data from a Map in a column?

```js
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final Map<String, String> profile = {
    'name': 'Name',
    'date of birth': 'Date',
    'profile update date': 'Date',
  };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final Map<String, String> profile = {
    'name': 'Name',
    'date of birth': 'Date',
    'profile update date': 'Date',
  };

    ListView.builder(
    itemCount: profile.length,
    builder:(context,index){
    return Column( children:[

    Text(profile[index]['name']),
SizedBox(height: 10),
     Text(profile[index]['date of birth']),
SizedBox(height: 10),
    Text(profile[index]['profile update date'])
    ]
    );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
children: [
Text(profile['name'])
]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the map into rows like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: profile.keys.map((key) => Row(children: [Text(profile[key]!)],)).toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```